# Angular: How to retain value in form fields after form submit?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am trying to submit/update a form, after submit form the value got disappered from the form fields, I want to retained/show the submit value, until and unless someone refresh the page

I do not want to follow localstorage method. I tried patch value method but it was also not working, I am clueless how to do this thing!  Might be there is issue in my function updatefromvalues

**component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" class="panel-title" color="accent">
  <ng-container *ngIf="!productGroup">
    {{ 'create-product-group' | translate }}
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="productGroup">
    {{ 'update-product-group' | translate }}
  </ng-container>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<mat-card-content class="p-a-md">
  <form [formGroup]="form" #formDirective="ngForm" (submit)="saveProductGroup()">
    <mat-form-field color="accent" class="full-width">
      <input type="text" matInput placeholder="{{ 'product-group-code' | translate }}" class="form-control"
        formControlName="code" required />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field color="accent" class="full-width">
      <input type="text" matInput placeholder="{{ 'product-group-type' | translate }}" class="form-control"
        formControlName="type" [matAutocomplete]="type" required />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-autocomplete #type="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let type of productGroupTypes" [value]="type">{{ type }}</mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>

    <mat-form-field color="accent" class="full-width">
      <input type="text" matInput placeholder="{{ 'product-group-description' | translate }}" class="form-control"
        formControlName="description" />
      <mat-hint *ngIf="productGroup && productGroup.description">
        {{ 'processes-might-depend-on-current-value' | translate }}
      </mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>

    <div fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
      <button
        class="text-uppercase p-x-lg m-x-auto m-t m-b"
        mat-raised-button
        type="submit"
        color="primary"
        [disabled]="form.invalid"
      >
        {{ 'save' | translate }}
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</mat-card-content>
```

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges, Output, SimpleChanges, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormGroupDirective } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonService } from '../../../../../\_services/common/common.service';
import { ProductGroupsService } from '../product-groups.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-group-data',
  templateUrl: './product-group-data.component.html',
})
export class ProductGroupDataComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() customerId: string;
  @Input() productGroup: Manufacturer.ProductGroup;
  @Input() productGroupTypes: string\[\];

  @Output() saved: EventEmitter\<Manufacturer.ProductGroup\> = new EventEmitter\<Manufacturer.ProductGroup\>();

  @ViewChild('formDirective') formDirective: FormGroupDirective;

  form: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    code: \['', Validators.required\],
    type: \['', Validators.required\],
    description: \[''\],
  });

constructor(
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  private commonService: CommonService,
  private productGroupsService: ProductGroupsService,
) { }

ngOnChanges({ productGroup }: SimpleChanges): void {
  const prevProductGroup = (productGroup?.previousValue || {}) as { \_id?: string };
  const currentProductGroup = (productGroup?.currentValue || {}) as { \_id?: string };
  if (prevProductGroup.\_id === currentProductGroup.\_id) {
    return;
  }
  this.updateFormValues(productGroup?.currentValue as Manufacturer.ProductGroup);
}

updateFormValues(productGroup: Manufacturer.ProductGroup): void {
    if (this.formDirective) {
      this.formDirective.resetForm();
    }

    if (productGroup) {
      this.form.controls.code.setValue(productGroup.code);
      this.form.controls.code.disable();
      this.form.controls.type.setValue(productGroup.type);
      this.form.controls.type.disable();
      this.form.controls.description.setValue(productGroup.description);
    } else {
      this.form.reset({
        code: { value: '', disabled: false },
        type: { value: '', disabled: false },
        description: '',
      });
    }

}

saveProductGroup(): void {
    if (!this.form.valid) {
      return;
    }

    const payload = { ...this.form.getRawValue() };
    const action = this.productGroup
      ? this.productGroupsService.updateProductGroup(this.customerId, payload)
      : this.productGroupsService.createProductGroup(this.customerId, payload);
    
    action.subscribe(({ message, data }) => {
      this.commonService.showUserNotification(message, 'ok');
      this.saved.emit(data);
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: form does not reset by default after submit. So your code is explicitely resetting it. We can see in your `updateFormValues` the form is reset. This method is called in your ngOnChanges. So your parent may change an Input, which triggers the reset.

Comment: So, Ideally, what do I need to do? @Random

Comment: What is your parent doing on `saved` event ?

Comment: check form validation, if productgroup exist, then update else create a new productgroup

Comment: this is already what `saveProductGroup` does. Does your parent doing it a second time ?

Comment: yes I guess, as I checked saveProductgroup fired 2 times, let me updated parent code too.